# AWS IAM Organization Issue - I can't see IAM users or any buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I know a lot of the stuff I already did is wrong.
Here's what happened:

I created a AWS Account and created an Organization.

I added someone else (let's call him Joe) to the orgnization as a root user.

Joe created a bunch of IAM users and those users started creating S3 buckets.

I log back into my root account and I cannot see any S3 buckets [image]

I see nothing running under EC2

[image]

And I don't see any IAM users

[image]

Basically it seems like we are in completely different world.

I had Joe create an IAM user for me and I was able to login through that account. Through that account, I see everything properly. It is really important that I figure this out because Joe will eventually leave the project and I need to make sure that everything is under the correct AWS root account.

I made sure that the regions are the same. I tried going to my root account and enabling service control policies and attaching FullAWSAccess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how Organizations works.

While you have consolidated billing and can enforce policies across the boundaries, Organizations is about consolidated, high-level management of accounts -- not a consolidated view that all subordinate resources percolate up into.

Accounts are still separate entities, and resources are still owned by and associated with the account that created them -- so unless you want the project to remain in a separate account, you don't want these things to be created in a separate account.

Possibly, the conceptual problem here is that you are considering an AWS account as belonging to a person -- Joe's account -- but that isn't how it's intended.  The individual accounts under an organzation are all intended to be your company's accounts -- a division's account, a project's account, etc.  AWS accounts "own" users (defined in IAM) -- users don't "own" AWS accounts.  The root credentials are the high-privileged credentials of an account, used only administratively for initial bootstrapping and as few other operstions as are necessary -- and are not intended to be used by an individual person beyond that.

See [Accessing a Member Account That Has a Master Account Access Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html#orgs_manage_accounts_access-cross-account-role) for the way Organizations allows you to switch your console view from account to account without logging out/logging in.

Comment: Hey Michael thanks so much for your response. Just to clarify, I was in the AWS Organizations tab and clicked "Add account" and "Invite account - Invite an existing AWS account to join your organization" to add Joe to the project. I Don't think that makes Joe an IAM user. Does this mean that Joe now needs to hand over access to that account? Joe will be leaving the project in a couple of months and I am trying to figure out how I can have access and control over everything before that happens. Is there no way to "transfer" everything over to the Master Account?

Comment: Correct.  Joe is not an IAM user, for purposes here -- he's an [account owner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/root-vs-iam.html) -- and he needs to hand over the root credentials for that account, to you, and he needs to be an IAM user, instead.  (If he is following best practices, he will already have an IAM user for himself and will not routinely use the root credentials.)  Then you'll want to update the email address for the root user and change the root password.  You can't transfer resources across account boundaries.